# How to properly visualize lloyds algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, k-means

for a computer science project I had to implement Lloyds-Algorithm which seems to have worked pretty good. I'd like to visualize the iterations. Which also works kind of already:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Variables to test
centroids = [[[2, 3],[6, 7]], 
             [[1, 2],[7, 8]]]
nearest_centroid_of_samples = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                               [0, 1, 1 , 1, 0]]
quant_error = [2.123,1.789]

# Actual code
i=0
for c,ncos, qe in zip(centroids, nearest_centroid_of_samples, quant_error):
    # My x and y values
    xx = [0, 4, 3, 8, 2]
    yy = [1, 3, 9, 5, 2]
    title = "Iteration Nr.%d" % (i)
    plt.title(title)
    # A text I would like to appear
    text = "Quantisierungsfehler: %f" % (qe)
    plt.text(12.5, 3.5, text)
    # Adding my clusters to the plot, ncos encodes the color
    plt.scatter(xx, yy, c=ncos, marker='o', alpha=1)
    # Here I'm adding my centroids (the middle of each cluster) to the plot
    for pos in c:
        plt.scatter(pos[0], pos[1], c="red", marker="+")
    i = i+1
    plt.pause(0.25)
plt.show()
```

This basically already gives me what I want. With only one little problem: It appears to draw each iteration on top of the previous one. Which is no problem for my data, since they match up perfectly and you can't see this. But the red marks for the centroids kinda bug out and keep being visible a little bit - and worse, the text I want to add has a longer decimal number which gets unreadable.

How do I need to plot this, that it draws everything new, but still in the same figure?

Best Regards

doofesohr

Edited in some representative values as per suggestion. These do not represent a result of Lloyds-Algorithm, but should still show where my problem is/was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes in your code-

```py
# to control the number of decimal places in the quantisation error
# change %f ----> %.2f for 2 decimal places or how many ever you want
text = "Quantisierungsfehler: %.2f" % (qe)

# to clear the contents of a figure and plot freshly add plt.cla() after plt.pause(0.25) i.e

plt.pause(0.25)
plt.cla()
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. I didn't even need to format my decimal number, since it was the same problem as the actual plot drawing. The newer number was just written on top of the older one.

Comment: You are welcome and do take Paul's advice and try to use object-oriented interface of matplotlib, it needs a bit more typing but it is a good coding practise to get habituated to. Cheers!

Comment: Right now, I'm actually trying to implement his version. It's definetly easier to understand than what I did come up.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the object-oriented interface to matplotlib where you act on the object direcly:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xx = samples[:, 0]
yy = samples[:, 1]
dots = ax.scatter(xx, yy, c='k', marker='o', alpha=1)
text = ax.text(12.5, 3.5, "placeholder")
for i, (c, ncos, qe) in enumerate(zip(centroids, nearest_centroid_of_samples, quant_error)):
    ax.set_title("Iteration Nr.%d" % (i))
    text.set_text("Quantisierungsfehler: %f" % (qe))
    dots.set_color(ncos)
    pos = numpy.array([[p[0], p[1]] for p in c])
    ax.scatter(pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1], c="red", marker="+")

    plt.pause(0.25)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think I do like your way object-oriented way since it seems to be more clear what actually happens and why it happens. Though I seem to have some trouble with the dots.set_color(ncos). I think I didn't explain it correctly: ncos is basically just an array that has the same length as samples, which has integer values, that describe which cluster they are in. Since set_color seems to want some kind of RGB value, it isn't satisfied with just an integer.

Comment: @doofesohr you should hard-code representative values of all of your variables. more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks Paul, will definetly do that next time (and will probably edit one in above). Would have solved the misunderstanding about ncos I guess.